# Why is the 0th term of the padovan sequence 1 but for fibonacci it is 0?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

**padovan numbers** are:

P(0)=1, P(1)=1, P(2)=1, P(3)=2, P(4)=2, P(5)=3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 16, 21, etc

WHERE P(n) = P(n-2) + P(n-3)

**fibonacci numbers** are:

F(0)=0, F(1)=1, F(2)=1, F(3)=2, F(4)=3, F(5)=5, 8, 13, 21, etc

WHERE F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)

**Question**

My question is, why not use P(0)=0 as follows:

P(0)=0, P(1)=1, P(2)=1, P(3)=1, P(4)=2, P(5)=2, P(6)=3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 16, 21, etc

Since this satisfies P(n) = P(n-2) + P(n-3)

Also, when looking at the Fibonacci squares we see the first visible term of the sequence is F(1)

[image]

With the Padovan triangles the first visible term of the sequence is P(0)?

[image]

Which seems inconsistent to me. Can anyone give a mathematical explanation as to why P(0)=1 ... many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [OEIS sequence A000931](https://oeis.org/A000931) is "Padovan sequence (or Padovan numbers): a(n) = a(n-2) + a(n-3) with a(0)=1, a(1)=a(2)=0." In contrast, your sequence $P(n) = A000931(n+5) = A134816(n+1).$ The OEIS entry also states

> The following are basically all variants of the same sequence: A000931, A078027, A096231, A124745, A133034, A134816, A164001, A182097, A228361 and probably A020720. However, each one has its own special features and deserves its own entry.

The point is that it is a matter of convenience and choice of where to start the sequence and what index to use. The same holds for the Fibonacci numbers. Some people choose $F(0)=F(1)=1$. About your specific choice of $P(0)=P(1)=P(2)=1,$ that is exactly A134816 except offset differs by 1. You are welcome to submit your different offset sequence to the OEIS, but unlikely to succeed.

However, the English Wikipedia article [Padovan sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padovan_sequence) uses your notation, initial values, and contains the spiral of triangles. It mentions the OEIS sequence A000931 but neglects to mention the indexing difference.

Answer (score 4):

Recurrence relations like those allow for going backwards; for instance we can define $F(-1)$ by $F(1)=F(0)+F(-1)$, so
$$
F(-1)=F(1)-F(0)=1
$$
Similarly, $F(-2)=F(0)-F(-1)=-1$ and so on. If we translate indices, we get a new Fibonacci-like sequence
$$
F'(0)=1,\quad F'(1)=0,\quad F'(n+2)=F'(n+1)+F'(n)
$$
and another one if we start from $-2$ and translate indices by $2$:
$$
F''(0)=-1,\quad F'(1)=1,\quad F''(n+2)=F''(n+1)+F''(n)
$$

If we apply the same idea to the Padovan sequence, we need $P(2)=P(0)+P(-1)$, so $P(-1)=P(2)-P(0)=0$ and we could define
$$
P'(0)=0,\quad P'(1)=1,\quad P'(2)=1,\quad P'(n+3)=P'(n+1)+P'(n)
$$
Nothing different and no real mathematical explanation. Just history.

Comment: Note that F(-n) = (-1)^n * F(n) when n>=0, which makes the choice F(0) = 0 more natural, as it makes the sequence symmetrical (apart from the sign).

Comment: @Sjoerd I'm inclined to think this stems from usual problems in considering where to start sequences; it's rather like a religious war between those who consider 0 a natural number and those who don't.

Answer (score 3):

That's cute. The sequence also follows
$$ P(n) = P(n-1) + P(n-5) \; , \;  $$
which directly explains the diagram of triangles. For example, from the diagram, $12 = 9+3$ and $16=12+4.$

Go Figure.

$$  \left(   x^{5}  -  x^{4}  - 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  -  x  - 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{5}  -  x^{4}  - 1 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  -  x  - 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  + 1 \right) }   $$

Comment: But this is true regardless of the indexing, what's the point?